# Error when downloading file with "/" or "\" in name

Tags: python, api, search

I'm using the freesound API to search and download sound clips to use in training a neural network. When the script comes across a file with a special character in the name, it will give an error and the script will stop. I would like to download the files it comes across with special characters and continue searching.

Here's my code: (The API key was in, just took it out for now)

```
import freesound, sys,os


client = freesound.FreesoundClient()
client.set_token("API KEY","token")

results = client.text_search(query="dog", page_size=150, 
fields="id,name,previews")



for sound in results:
    if "/" or "\\" or '.' not in sound.name:
        sound.retrieve_preview(".", sound.name+".mp3")
        print(sound.name)
```

Error Code:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\Dog eating Neck 
of Goose / Chewing / Breaking Bones.mp3'
```

Comment: `if "/" or "\\" or '.' not in sound.name`: doesn't do what you think it does. It's just `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if "/" or "\\" or '.' not in sound.name
```

is just `"/"` (truthy) ored with other expressions. Since it's "truthy", it stops here (short-circuit) and you always enter the `if`.

Trying natural language is not a proper way of coding in python.

Aside, note that the only problematic chars here are the slashes/backslashes (you should test colon as well), but dot is OK for a filename

To make it work properly, I would use `any` like this:

```
if not any(x in "/\\:" for x in sound.name):
```